# Showing that a non-homogenous differential equation has a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to show that the following initial-value problem

$$ \frac{x^{\prime}\left(t\right)}{1 + x \left(t\right)^{2}} + \frac{x\left(t\right)}{t} = 1 $$

with initial condition $x\left(t_{0}\right) = a > 0$ has a unique solution for $t \geq t_0 > 0$.

I know how to work with homogenous equations only, I tried to reorder the equation but failed. How can I approach such question?

Comment: Local existence and uniqueness follows from the standard theorems. The challenge is to show that there is no divergence to infinity at finite times, that a solution exists with domain $[t_0,\infty)$, if the task is to be interpreted that way. Note that $x'(t)=1+x(t)^2$ does not have this property.